# Search scope for multiple columns of data in Laravel Model

Tags: php, laravel, search, model, scope

I have a Model within Laravel called `Blah` (I named it this way because you can't simply name a class `Class`, so I changed the name temporarily).

Within the `classes` table, each row contains data like this:

```
   {
       year: "2015",
       term: "Summer",
       subject_code: "DIGM",
       course_no: "350",
       instr_type: "Lecture",
       instr_method: "Face To Face",
       section: "003",
       crn: "42953",
       course_title: "Digital Storytelling",
       credits: "3.0",
       day: "R",
       time: "06:30 pm - 09:20 pm",
       instructor: "Teacher Name",
       campus: "University Building",
       max_enroll: "18",
       enroll: "18",
       building: "PLACE",
       room: null,
       description: "By surfing the internet and playing computer games, by lectures, assigned readings, class screening, and research projects, this class explores the impact of digital media on art, design and daily living. This is a writing intensive course. ",
       pre_reqs: "",
       co_reqs: ""
   }
```

I developed a scope search query within my `Blah` Model like so:

```
/**
 * Search scope query
 *
 * @param string
 * @return QueryBuilder
 */
public function scopeSearch($query, $searchTerm) {
    return $query
        ->where('course_title', 'like', "%" . $searchTerm . "%");
}
```

The above scope search would allow me to search for the term `digital` and it would return the class called `Digital Storytelling`.

However, I would like to take it further - I would like to be able to, in the same search scope, perform a search like `DIGM 350` (these two data points are from `subject_code` and `course_no`) and it would bring up the same result.

So, searching `DIGM 350` and/or `digital` would bring up the same result. This would be part of my site's auto-search box.

Final Query:

```
/**
 * Search for course title or subject name
 * @param $query
 * @param $searchTerm Course Title or Subject Name
 * @return mixed
 */
public function scopeSearch($query, $searchTerm) {
    return $query
        ->where('course_title', 'like', '%' . $searchTerm . '%')
        ->orWhere(DB::raw("subject_code || ' ' ||  course_no"),
            'like',
            '%' . $searchTerm . '%'
        )
        ;
}
```

Thanks Ian.

Comment: If you want to make it specific, ie. search for `col_x AND col_y`, then you need dedicated method. However you're free to define it in the same scope method. Otherwise you can use https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence/wiki/Builder-searchable-and-more#searchable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [orWhere() method](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_orWhere) of the query builder to do something similar to your example:

```
    public function scopeSearch($query, $searchTerm) {
        return $query
            ->where('course_title', 'like', "%" . $searchTerm . "%")
            ->orWhere('subject_code', 'like', "%" . $searchTerm . "%")
            ->orWhere('course_no', 'like', "%" . $searchTerm . "%");
    }
```

However, the real problem here is that MySQL "like" queries may not be powerful enough to do what you're trying to do, since neither the `subject_code` or `course_no` columns contain the string "DIGM 350". You could do a like query on the concatination of those columns that would look something like this:

```
    public function scopeSearch($query, $searchTerm) {
        return $query
            ->where('course_title', 'like', "%" . $searchTerm . "%")
            ->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT_WS(' ',subject_code,course_no)"), 'like', "%" . $searchTerm . "%");
    }
```

That would do a like query matching any rows where the value of `subject_code` and `course_no` separated by a space contains the search string (or if the `course_title` contains it).

I think your needs may warrant an actual search engine, though.

Comment: The second one actually looks very promising!

Comment: I used your second code snippet, and I received the following warning: `PHP warning:  strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Grammar.php on line 52`. Note, I changed `DB` to my class name, `Blah`

Comment: I also noticed within your `CONCAT_WS`, the `course_no` isn't surrounded with single quotes. Is that intentional?

Comment: Good catch. Edited to fix the missing quotes typo.

Comment: You shouldn't replace `DB` with your class name. DB is a built in Laravel class, and it has a static method [raw()](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_raw) that allows you to substitute a raw SQL statement in place of a string that is intended to reference a column.

Comment: I gotcha, Ian. I re-ran your query using the input `digital`, and I got the following error: `Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: CONCAT_WS (SQL: select * from "classes" where "course_title" like %digital% or CONCAT_WS(' ','subject_code','course_no') like %digital%)'`. I am using SQLite, by the way, if that is causing the issue.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Are you using MySQL? My answer assumes you are, but you could replace the string being passed to `DB::raw()` with valid syntax for whichever DBMS you are using.

Comment: Edited to fix string vs. column reference mistake. Note that all args to `CONCAT_WS()` after the first should be column references, not strings, and therefore should not be in single-quotes.

Comment: Thanks Ian. I replaced the function of `CONCAT()` with the `||` operator in SQLite.